# CQRS Query Side implementation

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am a bit confused where to implement query side of application, atm i have next architecture:

```
Product.UI.Web.Admin (MVC)
Product.Application
 -CommandHandlers (e.g OrdersCommandHandler)
 -Commands (e.g CreateOrder)
Product.Domain
 -Model (Behavior-rich models / repository interfaces)
Product.Infrastructure (Base interfaces / classes)
Product.Persistence
 -ReadModel (EF Generated models)
 --Implementation (Repository implementations: FindByID / Save)
```

1. Should i place Queries namespace in Product.Application and they should directly access database from there? *(UI <= Product.Application <= Database)*
2. Should i create new assembly Product.Queries and Product.UI.Web.Admin should access it directly? *(UI <= Product.Queries)*
3. Should i add Queries namespace in Product.Application and also Create new Assembly Product.Reporting and let Application assembly use Reporting assembly via Queries namespace? *(UI <= Product.Application.Queries <= Product.Reporting)*

All three solutions return DTOs to UI.

I am thinking about solution #3 as it will be easy to use *Domain Services* in Queries to build results and also it will use Product.Reporting as *Data Access* which can be implemented using ADO.Net, Entity Framework or NHibernate. Or maybe i misunderstood something.

Please guide me and help me clear it up, thank you.

**UPDATE**
I came to fourth variant.

1. Created **Product.Infrastructure.Queries** assembly, there i have Database (dbcotnext) & ReadModel (EF Generated models & *generic query interfaces*) namespaces.
2. Added **DataModel** namespace in Product.Application, there i have DTOs to return to UI
3. Added **Queries** namespace in Product.Application, there i implement generic queries and use dbcontext to retrieve data, map to DTOs and return to UI.

Comment: What is in Product.Persistence.ReadModel? Is it database code that saves the read model?

Comment: What about declaring query interfaces in Product.Application.Queries and implement them in Product.Infrastructure.Queries?

Comment: @tomliversidge in Product.Persistence.ReadModel are Database Models generated by EF, in Implementation Repository receives Domain Model maps it to ReadModel and EF saves it, forgot to mention that i have repository interfaces in Domain Model.

Comment: @plalx hm, haven't thought about it, i will try it, atm i am looking for best practice to avoid huge refactoring in future ;) but there is one problem if i implement Queries in Infrastructure, some queries will have to use DomainServices which are implemented in Application Service Layer. I guess i should dependency inject them right?

Comment: Why do queries need domain services?

Comment: @tomliversidge there may be domain services that will be used in queries to form final data. e.g ProfitCalculator. I dont have OLAP database so i will have to calculate profits on a fly.

Comment: @plalx about your solution, can Product.Infrastructure.Queries see Product.Application.Queries, to implement its interfaces, is this dependency legal? maybe its better to have EF generated ReadModels, DBContext and Query Interfaces in Product.Infrastructure.Queries and implement in Product.Application.Queries?

Comment: @QuietNaN It's perfectly fine, that's dependency inversion. `Application` is  at a higher level than `infrastructure` just like `domain` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd just apply the dependency inversion principle here and have something like `Application.Queries` that defines interfaces and `Infrastructure.Queries` which implement these interfaces. However, I've also seen infrastructure concerns directly into the `Application` layer. For instance, this is what Vaughn Vernon did in [com.saasovation.collaboration.application.calendarCalendarEntryQueryService](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/application/calendar/CalendarEntryQueryService.java) of the SaasOvation collaboration BC.

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking about solution #3 as it will be easy to use Domain Services in Queries to build results and also it will use Product.Reporting as Data Access which can be implemented using ADO.Net, Entity Framework or NHibernate. Or maybe i misunderstood something.

yes I also think you misunderstood something.

firstly let's talk about what domain services are?:
when you have a domain concept that involves multiple entities but you’re
unsure about which entity “owns” the behavior. It doesn’t appear to belong to any of them.This pattern of thinking is a strong
indicator of the need for a domain service.
so when you are using cqrs, the domain services live in command side so the query side can not access to domain services, actually and naturally it doesn't need to domain services because the query side doesn't carry out any business logic.you should all time remember that Command side and Query side are completely independent.

another important characteristic of CQRS is that the ReadModel could use a low level data access techniques like ADO.Net or micro ORMs and query through demoralized tables for generate reports.all of this ideas is for performance considerations.furthmore as the system grows in future you could even launch Command and Query sides on two separate instance.